# How to make a slider fill the space between two textboxes

Tags: html, css, slider

I have a customised slider in between two textboxes (you can choose how to allocate 10 Euros between two options). Now my problem is that the slider won't fill the space between these two boxes but stays the same width. I'd like the width to be variable and not fixed so it adjusts to the screen. I played with it a bit but couldn't find a suitable solution.

[This is what it looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG6rB.png)

I gathered most of the code online rather than write it myself so the mistake might be in there without me realising.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.slider {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">10€/0€</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer" align="center">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">0€/10€</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the current situation @JuliusGuevarra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the slider and inputs in a div or add another classname after `row` and use flexbox to align the items.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;

}

.slidecontainer {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.slider {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row container">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">10€/0€</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">0€/10€</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But now my whole page looks somewhat deformed... The page headline is now to the left of the content and the whole page is basically sorted horizontally rather than vertically.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of that at the end of my question.

Comment: I guess you're using bootstrap and the classname ```container``` overrides the bootstrap container class. Can you try changing the classname to a different name and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: It looks alright again! However, the slider is now only on the left and doesn't span the whole space between the labels.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was even easier than Julius' approach. It was basically only one line (the flex-grow: 1) that was missing. This worked:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: auto;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">10€/0€</span>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" class="slider" id="myRange">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">0€/10€</span>
    </div>
</div>
```